# Reading from two dictionaries simultaneously in vb

Tags: vb.net, string, dictionary

I have two dictionaries set up in my program, and both contain the same set of names for the first element. My question is is there a way to read from both at the same time to display only one line with the second element of each of the dictionaries, and then do this for all names in the first element?

my current code to read from a single dictionary is:

```
For Each name As String In wordCount.Keys
        lineoutput &= name & " spoke a total of " & wordCount.Item(name) & " words." & vbCrLf
    Next
```

I have another dictionary named wordCount2 which I set up exactly like this that has the same names, but different number for the second element. Is there a way to access both of them so that I can have all the information about each name on the same line?

Comment: If the keys of both dictionaries are identical, you can just call the second dictionary like you do with the first one: `wordCount2.Item(name)`. But of course, only on condition that the keys are identical for both!

Comment: Give an example with real data. Otherwise hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a single dictionary instead of two.

Each element of that single dictionary would have an integer array or list, with two numbers.

I've made an example:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer())

        Dim myInts(1) As Integer
        myInts(0) = 5
        myInts(1) = 7

        Dim myInts2(1) As Integer
        myInts2(0) = 8
        myInts2(1) = 9

        dictionary.Add("name1", myInts)
        dictionary.Add("name2", myInts2)

        For Each element In dictionary
            Console.WriteLine(element.Key + ": " + element.Value(0).ToString + ", " + element.Value(1).ToString)
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```